# Chromium issue with Error initializing NSS with a peristent database NSS error code: -8023

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

We wrote a Print PDF lambda function generates a PDF file using puppeteer from HTML content sent to it in the SQS message.  It is deployed as a lambda in aws. The function also allows uploading of pictures.  The pdf is then stored in a s3 bucket. We are using chrome-aws-lambda and puppeteer. (chrome-aws-lambda@8.0.2 puppeteer-core@8.0.0). When we tried to upload pictures we are getting following:

```
error: Error initializing NSS with a persistent database  NSS error code: -8023.
```

It is then followed by

```
ERROR      Invoke Error       {
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!",
    "stack": [
        "Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:51:147",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:62",
        "    at Array.map (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Object.emit (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:43)",
        "    at CDPSession.emit (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)",
        "    at CDPSession._onClosed (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:247:14)",
        "    at Connection._onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:128:21)",
        "    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:17:30)",
        "    at WebSocket.onClose (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)",
        "    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)"
    ]
}
```

A pdf file with "access denied" is then created in s3 bucket.  Please advise and recommendation a solution.